# How to assign value to quote number that is derieved from related opportunity

Tags: opportunity, quote

A new Quote assigns "Q-NNNNN" value to a newly generated quote. We want to assign value of opportunity number to a newly generated quote. For instance the Quote number will look something similar to "Q--1". Is it possible to do this?

Comment: A trigger on Quote would be needed to do this

Comment: If you are using standard object.you can't do it a direct way.(or) create a custom field in quote object

Answer (score 1):

This is possible on the standard `Quote` object. What's more, you can even do it declaratively!

**Workflow to the rescue**

You can create a workflow rule that only runs when a new record is inserted. Set it to run on all newly inserted `Quotes` by choosing the option to use a formula to use as the workflow rule criteria, and simply put `true` into the formula window.

Then, create a workflow field update, and choose `Quote Name` as the field to update.

Click the little radio button to use a formula to set the value of the field. The formula that you'll use is pretty simple, and should look something like this:

> `'Q-' & Opportunity.Opportunity_Number__c & '-' & NOW()`

Note that there isn't a standard 'Opportunity Number' field. I used the field name from my org. If yours is different, you'll need to modify the formula accordingly.

The ampersand `&` in the formula is used to concatenate strings.

Sequential quote numbers that start over from 1 on each new `Opportunity` complicates things slightly.

`NOW()` returns the current date and time, which should be sufficiently unique.

Having an auto-number field on the Quote is an option, but you wouldn't be able to start over from 1 for the first `Quote` on subsequent `Opportunities` (it would keep incrementing, just like an Opportunity number)

**But I reeeeeeally want sequential quote numbers**

If you really want sequentially numbered `Quotes` on each `Opportunity`, e.g. `Q-<Opp Number>-1`, `Q-<Opp Number>-2`, and so on, it certainly  is possible, but requires a bit more work. Still no code required, though.

Create a new rollup summary field on `Opportunity` that counts the number of quotes. For sake of example, I'll call this field `Num_Quotes__c`

Keeping in mind the [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), `Num_Quotes__c` will not be updated until after this workflow rule fires. That means to get the proper quote number, you'll need to add 1 to `Num_Quotes__c`.

The example formula becomes:

> `'Q-' & Opportunity.Opportunity_Number__c & '-' & (Opportunity.Num_Quotes__c + 1)`

Comment: Derek, Pavan, Ankit,

Thanks a lot for your replies. I was able to change quote number in standard quote with the help of trigger.